# Log a list of files and open them with vscode CLI (creating a Shell macro)

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, macros, zsh, git-grep

I'm trying to create a macro on my shell.

The operation I'm trying to automate is this one:

> Find all the files containing `TEXT_TO_SEARCH`, and open them with VSCODE

I can do this with a one-liner

```bash
$ code $(git grep TEXT_TO_SEARCH | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u)
```

so my first step was adding the following function to `~/.zshrc`

```bash
cgrep() {
  code $(git grep "$1" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u)
}
```

and then

```bash
$ cgrep TEXT_TO_SEARCH
```

This works.

Now I'm trying to add an extra feature:

> Before opening each file with VSCode, echo to the console "Opening FILE_NAME"

First I've tried this

```bash
cgrep() {
  grep_results=$(git grep "$1" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u)
  for file in $grep_results; do
    echo "Opening $file"
    code $file
  done
}
```

Note that `grep_results` is a "vertical list" i.e.

```bash
$ echo $grep_results

src/path1/FILE1.py
src/path2/FILE2.py
src/path3/FILE3.py
```

This way the for loop considers the first `file` as the whole `grep_results` and it opens `FILE3.py` (not `src/path3/FILE3.py`).

I've also tryied this (with the help of GPT)

```bash
cgrep() {
  grep_results=$(git grep "$1" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u)
  echo "$grep_results" | while read -r file; do
    echo "Opening $file"
    code "$file"
  done
}
```

This way I can open just the first grepped file, and I get a message I don't want from VSCode and I don't actually understand

```bash
$ cgrep TEXT_TO_SEARCH

Opening src/path1/FILE1.py
Run with 'code -' to read from stdin (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, with the help of @[Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387076/gilles-so-stop-being-evil) in Unix&Linux StackExchange (his full answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763659/log-a-list-of-files-and-open-them-with-vscode-cli)).

This is my final version

```bash
cgrep() {
    grep_results=($(git grep -l $1))
    for file in "${grep_results[@]}"; do
        echo "Opening $file"
        code $file
    done
}
```

Comment: Your solution would - even in zsh - break, if one of the filenames contains a space. In addition, backquotes are obsolete, and while they still work for compatibility, it would be better not to use them in an answer.

Comment: If I put blank spaces in file names I think I would be fired  in any case, thanks for the support and advice on backquotes

Comment: @tripleee: The `$1` is no problem. This code is for zsh.

Comment: I havs sympathy for your employers, but from my many years of experience, I know of projects, where spaces in filenames are shamelessly used. For the benefit of people who have to endure such harsh working conditions, you could at least point out this danger in your posting. After all, answers to questions should be as helpful as possible for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is executed exactly once (as you can see when you run the code with `-x` turned on), because you have only a single variable in the list, `$grep_results`. You could split the variable on white space (i.e. the newlines in the variable) by writing

```
for file in ${(z)grep_results}
```

but this still would fail, if one of the files contains embedded spaces. This problem also exists in your own "final version", where you replaced the variable by an array.

What you really want to do, is follow your original approach, but split the result of your pipeline by newlines and not white space:

```
for file in ${(f)grep_results}
```